# jQuery Text Effect Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a text effect plugin that works great when I enter text into the text box and click the button, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/bushell/5ttdejk3/

However, what I am trying to do is now load the data directly into the #digits div from an external js file. Something like this:

```
function loadJSON(from, to, petrolPrice, mpg)
{

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/petrol/petrolData.php?from="+from+"&to="+to+"&petPrice="+petrolPrice+"&mpg="+mpg, function(data) {
       var mins = data.Minutes;
       var target  = $('#digits'); 
        var output= data.Origin + " " + data.Destination + "-mins:-" + mins + "--" + data.PetrolCost;

        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=output;



target.shuffleText(mins);



  });

}
```

Some reason its not working, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `mins` variable is a number, it won't work, shuffleText expects a string:

```
target.shuffleText(''+mins);
```